# Why hyperlinks and Buttons doesnt fire

Tags: html, css, button, hyperlink, position

Can anyone tell me whats wrong with the hyperlinks (orange buttons) in this page as they dont fire? though the links are correct!

http://www.venusglass.net/new/projects/

I'm using Bootstrap framework and SilverStripe CMS
HTML:

```
<div class="project-gallery">

          <figure class="item"> <a href="/new/projects/ghoo-complex/"> <img src="/new/assets/project-teaser/ghoo-complex-teaser.jpg" alt="ghoo complex teaser" class="img-responsive" width="960" height="720"></a>
            <figcaption>
              <h3>مجتمع قو الماس خاورمیانه</h3>
              <p>V-Coll, V-Guard, V-Temp</p>
              <p><a href="/new/projects/ghoo-complex/" class="btn btn-primary">مشاهده</a></p>
            </figcaption>
          </figure>

          <figure class="item"> <a href="/new/projects/mellat-complex/"> <img src="/new/assets/project-teaser/mellat-complex-teaser.jpg" alt="mellat complex teaser" class="img-responsive" width="960" height="720"></a>
            <figcaption>
              <h3>پردیس سینمایی ملت</h3>
              <p>V-Cool, V-Temp</p>
              <p><a href="/new/projects/mellat-complex/" class="btn btn-primary">مشاهده</a></p>
            </figcaption>
          </figure>

          <figure class="item"> <a href="/new/projects/tehran-international-tower/"> <img src="/new/assets/project-teaser/tehran-intl-tower-teaser.jpg" alt="tehran intl tower teaser" class="img-responsive" width="960" height="720"></a>
            <figcaption>
              <h3>برج بین&zwnj;المللی تهران</h3>
              <p>V-Cool, V-Lam, V-Temp</p>
              <p><a href="/new/projects/tehran-international-tower/" class="btn btn-primary">مشاهده</a></p>
            </figcaption>
          </figure>

        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.project-gallery {
  margin: 1.5em 0;
  padding: 0;
  -moz-column-gap: 1.5em;
  -webkit-column-gap: 1.5em;
  column-gap: 1.5em;
  font-size: .85em;
}
.project-gallery .item {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0.8em;
  margin: 0 0 1.5em;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 0 #ccc;
}
.emph-gallery .project-gallery .item {
  padding: 0;
}
.project-gallery .item figcaption {
  padding: 0.8em 0 0;
}
.emph-gallery .project-gallery .item figcaption {
  padding: 0.8em;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.project-gallery {
  -moz-column-count: 1;
  -webkit-column-count: 1;
  column-count: 1;
}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
.project-gallery {
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
.project-gallery {
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;
}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
.project-gallery {
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;
}
}
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question

Comment: Check your browser console for errors. You have an error in a JS click handler for those links in http://www.venusglass.net/new/themes/venus/js/main.js

Comment: And run your page through a HTML validator and check the developer tools console.

Comment: @MichaelCoker Thanks a million! that helped me to fix it!

Comment: @AliAlamshahi awesome, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake! the div had a class which was declared in a java-script and that made the errors. just changed the class name and everything works now.